# Is there an example that $\max\{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$ converge to a degenerate distribution function?

Tags: probability, statistics

In [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher–Tippett–Gnedenko_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem), we know that

> [image]

Is there an example that $\max\{X_1,\dots, X_n\}$ converge to a degenerate distribution function?

Comment: If the $X_i$ all take a fixed value with probability one, this will happen.

Comment: @PhoemueX Can you explain why? If $X_i=1$ for every $i=1,\dots, n$, It becomes $\lim P(1-b_n/a_n\le x)$?